# lspci dont see nvidia gpu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04

I have got nvidia 350 mx (os:ubuntu 22 04) and it doesn't show up in lspci. I installed nvidia-driver 510 (also nvidia-driver-510 is selected in software & updates):

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510
and sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Then I chose this in Nvidia settings, but still nothing. Nvidia card show up in

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'lspci | grep VGA
```

but not in

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Can someone help? Can u tell me what can I do to see Nvidia in `lspci` or how can I check is Nvidia GPU on?

[enter image description here]

[image: 1]

Comment: You are seeing it in `lspci`. No problem, nothing to fix. All you need to understand is you're grep'ing the wrong term.

Comment: Ok thanks, how can I check What GPU card is using now?

Comment: At Nvidia X Server Settings (your pow screenshot). It should also be reflected at system settings > about.

Comment: oh, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jeremi probably you have the same issue as mine , after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04,it is recognizing my nvidia gpu as only 3D controller instead of VGA , see [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423623/nvidia-graphic-card-is-recognized-as-3d-controller-in-ubuntu-22-04)